# drf_yasg doesn't take TYPE_ARRAY as a valid type

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

the drf_yasg swagger generator doesnt take TYPE_ARRAY as a valid parameter type.
the implementation is as follows

```
from drf_yasg import openapi
param1 = openapi.Parameter('param_name',
                            in_=openapi.IN_QUERY,
                            description='description of param',
                            type=openapi.TYPE_ARRAY,
                            required=True
                            )
```

whereas the [documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/drf-yasg/latest/drf-yasg.pdf) of drf_yasg suggests that it takes openapi.TYPE_ARRAY as valid type.

the error that the generators throws is

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/drf_yasg/codecs.py", line 73, in encode
    raise SwaggerValidationError("spec validation failed", errors, spec, self)
drf_yasg.errors.SwaggerValidationError: spec validation failed
```

is there some configuration that i am missing or something because TYPE_STRING,TYPE_NUMBER works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `Parameter` of `TYPE_ARRAY` requires the `items` key:

```
param1 = openapi.Parameter('param_name',
                            in_=openapi.IN_QUERY,
                            description='description of param',
                            type=openapi.TYPE_ARRAY,
                            items=openapi.Items(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING)  # <------
                            required=True
)
```

See the [OpenAPI 2.0 specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameterObject) for more details.